# VBA replace only whole string

Tags: vba, excel, replace, syntax

Using replace in VBA, it `replaces` all occurances of `find`. How do i limit it to only replace if `find` is the whole string?

```
Cells.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="n/a", LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Replaces `12034` and `0`  with  `12n/a34` and `n/a`

Instead will ignore `12034` and only replace `0` with `n/a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `LookAt:=xlPart` to `LookAt:=xlWhole`

`xlPart` will match any text within the cell, whereas `xlWhole` will match only the entire cell entry.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if there was a third option: to look for any Whole word IN the entire String. Unfortunately it is either any part of the word or the entire string.

E.g. when trying to remove "in" in the string "I'm going to ride in a car" will either match nothing with xlWhole, or all with xlPart, resulting in the unwanted "I'm gog to ride a car".

This less nice solution works for us, but I'd rather use the other one, if only it had that 3rd flag.

```
stopwords = Array("in", "the")
text = "I'm going to ride in a car"

For Each c In stopwords    
    text = Replace(text, " " & c & " ", " ")
Next c
```

It's been 7 years for this thread, but maybe somebody can use this solution, or provide a better one for me ;)